# Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE "some number"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.0

today when i start new  project an error occured said plugin is too old.
 and i click fix plugin version and fix project but the same error is still there after fixing plugin. Here is my application gradle file.
'

> buildscript {
>      repositories {
>          jcenter()
>      }
>     dependencies {
>          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'
>
> ```
>    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>    // in the individual module build.gradle files
> ```
>
> }
>   }
>
> allprojects {
>      repositories {
>         jcenter()
>      }
>   }'
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>      delete rootProject.buildDir
>   }

Comment: Right Click on Project-->Open Module Settings in that check the go to project and check the gradle version and android gradle plugin version used. It should be compatible.

Comment: Beta 3 version of android studio works with beta 3 version of android gradle build plugin. And so on.

Comment: Which version of AS are you using? Which version of gradle wrapper are you using?

Comment: 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'

Answer (score 0):

Just set new ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE value using terminal

`launchctl setenv ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE <your-value-on-error-message>`

Need to do this every day